# How to read in "\r\n" as a string? trying to split data from an incoming message

Tags: c#, string, sorting, networking, network-protocols

I am having an issue trying to receive a string that I need to split as one part of the string has a name and the other part of the string has a location. although I am unsure how to split this data, as when it is received, it should come back as:

"POST /JACK\r\n\r\nis at this building\r\n"

name part is "POST /JACK\r\n\r\n".

location part is "is at this building\r\n".

The code I use to read this incoming message is:

```
line = sr.ReadLine();
```

The message is sent through a connected socket to me by an address and port. But when I receive this message, line is returned as:
"POST /JACKis at this building"

I did try and use this code before:

```
            var str = line;
            var Sorted = str.Replace("\\r\\n", System.Environment.NewLine);
            string[] splitted = Sorted.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Which basically is meant to look for lines in the string so it can split and sort it but from the looks of it, I cannot use it if I am not getting the "\r\n" from the message, which means I cannot split it.

How would I split the information from the message provided that the message is delivered as: "POST /JACKis at this building" delivered to me?

Comment: OK so what is the rule for where the break should happen

Comment: the break? I'm unsure what you mean, if you are on about the message, I cannot do a ReadToEnd(); as that causes an error (the message does not tell when to stop). So I have to use a ReadLine();. I am trying to basically get that message into args. so if I had for example: 
string[] line = null;
line = sr.readline();

And I had that incoming message, I am trying to basically make it so I can split the message up by each new line. But I am having trouble over it. I'm sure it's simpler than it is but I am confused.

Comment: you ask 'how can I chop this up?' "POST /JACKis at this building" My question is - what is the chopping rule. Do you want "P","OST", "/JACKis", " at this building". Or maybe "POST /", "JACK is at the building", or what

Comment: I want it to be that the variable Name contains "jack" and the variable Location contains "at this building". I know that I can use things like .remove(0,6) or .replace("POST /", ""); which I have used. The message is like that because it comes formatted in a 0.9 protocol

Comment: so I guess I want it to be "JACK" "is at the building".

Comment: so all caps? "POST /JANETis in the building" or is it a fixed length ie POST /xxxx?. Ie how to parse "POST /JANetis as the building" I assume it doesnt always say "is at the build"

Comment: `ReadLine` should only return the characters up to the next `\r\n` or `\n`. You could call it multiple times to receive each line?

Comment: Thankyou I just realised that. After spending hours I have only just noticed what you mentioned. Although I would prefer them oved into a string array which I dont know how. I managed to make an if statement for 2 strings in a while loop that will basically say if string1 is null, assign value. else if other string is null, assign value.